# Locally preservation of coordinate systems

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

> Let $\phi:M\to N $ be a smooth map and let $p\in M$ be a point at which $d\phi_p$ is a linear isomorphism.
> Given a coordinate system $\zeta$ at $p$ or $\eta$ at $\phi(p)$ the other can be selected so that $\phi$ preserves coordinates $y^i(\phi_q)=x^i(q)$ for $q$ near $p$.
> Then $d\phi\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$ and if $f\in\mathscr{T}(N)$

> $$\frac{\partial f\circ \phi}{\partial x^i}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^i}\circ \phi$$ near $p$

In the first part, I used the inverse function theorem. Since we have a linear isomorphism, there is a neighbourhood around p and one around $\phi(p)$, where phi is a diffeomorphism.

Then if I pick $\eta=\phi\circ\zeta^{-1}$ is a coordinate system in the neighbourhood of $\phi(p)$, the same applies if I choose $\zeta=\phi^{-1}\circ\eta^{-1}$. I think this proves the assertion.

Regarding the second part, I am confused once I am not able to relate to the specific coordinates $x^i$ and $y^i$

**Question**:

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the chain rule. Observe that $\partial (f\circ \phi)/\partial x^i$ is the derivative $d(f\circ\phi)$ acting on the tangent vector $\partial/\partial x^i$ and from the previous part we know what $d\phi$ does to $\partial/\partial x^i$.